# how to derive the equality: $E X 1_{X > b} = \int_0^\infty dy \mathbb{P}\{X 1_{X > b} > y\}$?

Tags: probability-theory, proof-explanation

[image]

Can someone explain how to derive this equality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\mathbb{E}\left[\xi^p\right]= p\int_0^\infty \mathbb{P}(\xi>t)t^{p-1} \, \text{d}t = p\int_0^\infty \mathbb{P}(\xi\geq t)t^{p-1} \, 
 \text{d}t $$
for all $p>0$.

*Proof.* By Fubini's theorem and calculus, we get
\begin{align}
    \mathbb{E}\left[\xi^p\right] &= \int_\Omega  \xi^p \, \text{d} \mathbb{P}\\ 
    &=  p\int_\Omega \int_{0}^\xi t^{p-1}\, \text{d}t \,\text{d}\mathbb{P}\\
     &= p\int_\Omega \int_{0}^\infty 1_{\{\xi>t\}} t^{p-1}\, \text{d}t \,\text{d}\mathbb{P}\\
     &= p\int_{0}^\infty t^{p-1}\int_\Omega  1_{\{\xi>t\}}\,\text{d}\mathbb{P}\, \text{d}t \\
    & = p\int_0^\infty \mathbb{P}(\xi>t)t^{p-1} \, \text{d}t .
 \end{align}
The proof of the second expression is similar.